# Spinner inside dynamic listview

Tags: android, listview, spinner, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a listview with custom rows, every row contains a spinner. I am filling the row with data like this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
HashMap row = new HashMap();

row.put("Land_Links", c.getString(1));
row.put("Land_Rechts", c.getString(2));
row.put("Datum", c.getString(11));
row.put("Tijd", c.getString(10));

list.add(row);
```

And after I am adding it to a simpleAdapter and then listview.setAdapter.
That all works perfect.
I can't figure out how to populate and set an onclicklistener for the spinners.

Can you tell me how I should resolve this problem?

edit:

With every row I create 2 new spinners are created, I want to populate and set the `onclick` listener to both of the new spinners.
I created an array with the values that need to be populated in the spinners.(`R.array.score`)

When I try to populate the spinners by adding them to my example above i get the exception spinner is not a view that can be bounds by this simpleAdapter.

My target: To get one loop in which the textviews are populated the spinners are populated and the `onclick`listeners are set for the spinners.

Comment: what you need? how onClickListener work or something else? give specific details..

Answer (score -1):

You should to extends an Adapter (BaseAdapter, SimpleAdapter ... ) and in the getView (the name is not allways this but normally is for all the types of adapters like baseAdapter ) method you can set onClickListener to the spinners.

Here you can find information about ArrayAdapter 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Here the code of a BaseAdapter

public class FrontPageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<Item> rssItems;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public FrontPageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Item> items){
    super();
    rssItems = items;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount(){
    return rssItems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position){
    return rssItems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position){
    return getItem(position).hashCode();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.frontpage_item, null);

    // Get the item
    Item ls = (Item)getItem(position);
    if (ls == null)
        return convertView;

    //Set the title
    String title = ls.getTitle();
    if (title == null || title.equals("")){
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FrontPageItemHeader)).setText("");
    }
    else{
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FrontPageItemHeader)).setText(title);  
    }



    //Obtenemos el contenido. En caso de ser null obtenemos la descripcion
    //  String description = ls.getContent();
    String subtitle= ls.getDescription();
    if (subtitle == null || subtitle.length() == 0){
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FrontPageItemText)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.FrontPageItemText)).setText(Html.fromHtml(subtitle));
    }

     // Other views, for example your spinner




    return convertView;
}
```

}